# GET request to ups.com returns 403 one one particular host only

Tags: php, curl

UPS has recently [raised their security standards](https://www.ups.com/us/en/help-center/technology-support/data-security.page).  As a result, **on one host in particular**, I get a 403 when attempting to do a GET to their rates API:

"http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi?accept_UPS_license_agreement=yes&10_action=4&13_product=GNDRES&14_origCountry=US&15_origPostal=98584&19_destPostal=33773&22_destCountry=US&23_weight=2.375&47_rate_chart=Regular+Daily+Pickup&48_container=00&49_residential=1"

(I'm doing the GET in PHP using cURL.)  I notice that this host is using an older cURL (7.19.7) and and older NSS (NSS/3.27.1), but I have other hosts that are using these versions where the GET will work.

What can I do to track down the issue?

Comment: It seems to me that you've tracked down the issue already.  Update cURL so that new versions of TLS will be used.

Comment: I have tried it is working for me

Comment: @Brad I would believe that, except that I have other hosts with the same old versions of cURL and NSS that *do* work.

Comment: Well perhaps you've been spamming them for an extended period of time from that host (definitions of "spam" and "extended" may vary) and they've blacklisted its IP address?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi?accept_UPS_license_agreement=yes&10_action=4&13_product=GNDRES&14_origCountry=US&15_origPostal=98584&19_destPostal=33773&22_destCountry=US&23_weight=2.375&47_rate_chart=Regular+Daily+Pickup&48_container=00&49_residential=1",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

Response:

```
UPSOnLine4%1DM%98584%US%33773%US%108%3%130.41%0.00%130.41% 8:00 A.M.%
4%1DA%98584%US%33773%US%108%3%98.23%0.00%98.23%10:30 A.M.%
4%1DP%98584%US%33773%US%138%3%89.08%0.00%89.08%End of Day%
4%2DA%98584%US%33773%US%208%3%45.79%0.00%45.79%End of Day%
4%3DS%98584%US%33773%US%308%3%36.05%0.00%36.05%End of Day%
4%GND%98584%US%33773%US%008%3%16.86%0.00%16.86%End of Day%
```

Comment: thanks for your effort - I know this will work *on every host except the one that is having the problem*.  It's a host-specific issue.